# Comparing DateTime values in SelectCommand

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, select

I am working on ASP.net application with a MS Access database.I want to only display those list of entries whose DateTime value is greater than the present date and time.
I am having difficulty in comparing in SelectCommand, as to how to pass the datetime parameter.
My code is as follows:
`

```
        SelectCommand="SELECT `ID`, `eventname`, `description`, `venue`, `coordinator`, `time` FROM `upcoming` ORDER BY `time` WHERE (`time`&gt;=?)" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE `upcoming` SET `eventname` = ?, `description` = ?, `venue` = ?, `coordinator` = ?, `time` = ? WHERE `ID` = ?">

        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="eventname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="venue" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="coordinator" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="time" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="time" Type="DateTime" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>`
```

Please tell me how can i pass the datetime value to the SelectParameters through this code.
Thank You for looking in it.

Comment: That does not look like an Access SELECT statement. Back-ticks are not used in Access and Time is a reserved word requiring square brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use

```
SELECT ID, eventname, description, venue, coordinator, [time] 
FROM upcoming
WHERE time > NOW()
ORDER BY time
```

`NOW()` is a builtin function in Access, so you don't need to pass it to the query

Comment: Time is a reserved word, so [Time].

Comment: @Marco but my format is "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm", so how can i change the now() format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" to this within the query itself?

Comment: @Anant Gupta: inside any database (usually), a DateTime value is always stored as a _double_. Format you use or declare is the way you want datetime presented to you/user!!

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm` is a string representation of the date value. You should mostly not be worrying about that in SQL, as it's a presentation-level issue. Instead, as @Marco says, the real date/time value will be what is used. The only time one has to worry about the string representation is for ambiguous date formats encoded as string representations (Access/Jet/ACE SQL is hardwired to use US format, so if you're not in the US, you need to use a format that can't be interpreted two ways, e.g., "d-mmm-yyyy").

Comment: Thank you for the help, but now when I'm using the condition" [time]>NOW()" in the query given above, even throughout he date entry is 01/01/2020, still it is not selected.

Comment: @Anant Gupta: post your table definition please